# Fragment popbackstack trigger lifecyclescope collect

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment-lifecycle

**Situation**

I submit data `setTripDeliver`, the collect works fine (trigger LOADING and then SUCCESS). I pressed a button go to next fragment B (using `replace`). After that, I press back button (using `popbackstack`). the collect SUCCESS triggered.

**Codes Related**

These codes at the `FragmentA.kt` inside `onViewCreated`.

```
private fun startLifeCycle() {
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            launch {
                collectTripDeliver()
            }
            launch {
                collectTripReattempt()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These codes when to submit data at a button `setOnClickListener`.

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    viewModel.setTripDeliver(
         verificationCode,
         remark
    )
}
```

Method to collect flow `collectTripReattempt()`

```
private suspend fun collectTripReattempt() {
        viewModel.tripReattempt.collect {
            when (it) {
                is Resource.Initialize -> {

            }
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                Log.i("???","collectTripReattempt loading")
                handleSaveEarly()
            }
            is Resource.Success -> {
                val error = it.data?.error
                if (error == null) {
                    Tools.showToast(requireContext(), "Success Reattempt")
                    Log.i("???","collectTripReattempt Success")
             
                } else {
                    Tools.showToast(requireContext(), "$error")
                }
                handleSaveEnding()
            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                handleSaveEnding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below codes are from `ViewModel`.

```
private val _tripDeliver =
    MutableStateFlow<Resource<TripDeliverResponse>>(Resource.Initialize())
val tripDeliver: StateFlow<Resource<TripDeliverResponse>> = _tripDeliver
```

This method to call repository.

```
suspend fun setTripDeliver(
    verificationCode: String?,
    remark: String?
) {
    _tripDeliver.value = Resource.Loading()
    try {
        val result = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
            val tripDeliverParameter = DeliverParameter(
                verificationCode,
                remark
            )
            val response = appRepository.setTripDeliver(tripDeliverParameter)
            Resource.getResponse { response }
        }
        _tripDeliver.value = result
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        when (e) {
            is IOException -> _tripDeliver.value =
                Resource.Error(messageInt = R.string.no_internet_connection)
            else -> _tripDeliver.value =
                Resource.Error("Trip Deliver Error: " + e.message)
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
2021-07-09 19:56:10.946 7446-7446/com.package.app I/???: collectTripReattempt loading
2021-07-09 19:56:11.172 7446-7446/com.package.app I/???: collectTripReattempt Success
2021-07-09 19:56:17.703 7446-7446/com.package.app I/???: collectTripReattempt Success
```

As you can see, the last `Success` is called again AFTER I pressed back button (`popbackstack`)

**Question**

How to make it trigger once only? Is it the way I implement it is wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution, thanks to @Nurseyit Tursunkulov for giving me a clue. I have to use `SharedFlow`.

At the `ViewModel`, I replace the initialize with these:

```
private val _tripDeliver = MutableSharedFlow<Resource<TripDeliverResponse>>(replay = 0)
val tripDeliver: SharedFlow<Resource<TripDeliverResponse>> = _tripDeliver
```

At the `replay` I have to use `0`, so this `SharedFlow` will trigger once. Next, change `_tripDeliver.value` to `_tripDeliver.emit()` like the codes below:

```
fun setTripDeliver(
    verificationCode: String?,
    remark: String?
) = viewModelScope.launch {
    _tripDeliver.emit(Resource.Loading())

    if (verificationCode == null && remark == null) {
        _tripDeliver.emit(Resource.Error("Remark cannot be empty if verification is empty"))
        return@launch
    }

    try {
        val result = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
            val tripDeliverParameter = DeliverParameter(
                verificationCode,
                remark,
            )
            val response = appRepository.setTripDeliver(tripDeliverParameter)
            Resource.getResponse { response }
        }

        _tripDeliver.emit(result)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        when (e) {
            is IOException -> _tripDeliver.emit(Resource.Error(messageInt = R.string.no_internet_connection))
            else -> _tripDeliver.emit(Resource.Error("Trip Deliver Error: " + e.message))
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this answer will help the others also.

Answer (score 2):

This is not problem of your implementation this is happening because of **stateIn()** which use used in your `viewModel` to convert regular flow into `stateFlow`
If according to your code snippet the *success* is triggered once again, then why not *loading* has triggered?
as per article, it is showing the `latest cached value` when you left the screen and came back you got the latest cached value on view.
Resource:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-livedata-to-kotlins-flow-379292f419fb 
`The latest value will still be cached so that when the user comes back to it, the view will have some data immediately.`

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine you can use the event wrapper class

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because of coldFlow, you need a HotFlow. Another option is to try to hide and show fragment, instead of replacing. And yet another solution is to keep this code in viewModel.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I think your way of using coroutines in lifeScope is incorrect. After the lifeScope status of FragmentA is at Started again, the coroutine will be restarted:

```kotlin
launch {
   collectTripDeliver()
}
launch {
   collectTripReattempt()
}
```

So I think: You need to modify this way:

```kotlin
private fun startLifeCycle() {
     viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        launch {
           collectTripDeliver()
        }
        launch {
           collectTripReattempt()
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I thought the usage `launch` cannot be used for `flow` .

Comment: That's not correct solution. because if the app move to background while do job. and get result in the background it will cause a crash.
I strongly recommend use 
` viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)`